# Html.TextBox helper usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

Hi I am trying to convert the following HTML input into razor html.textbox helper using vb syntax

```
<input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearchTransactionNumber", "Home")" class="form-control" id="TransactionNumber" placeholder="Transaction Number">
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom attributes to HTML elements created by HTML helpers by defining a new dictionary like so:

```
@Html.TextBox("q", Request("q"),
               New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From
               {
                   { "data-autocomplete-source", Url.Action("QuickSearchTransactionNumber", "Home")},
                   {"class", "form-control"}, {"id", "TransactionNumber"},
                   {"placeholder", "Transaction Number"}
               })
```

This outputs the following HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" data-autocomplete-source="/Home/QuickSearchTransactionNumber" id="TransactionNumber" name="q" placeholder="Transaction Number" type="text" value="" />
```

Documentation for this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505258(v=vs.108).aspx

If you want to use a `LabelFor` in your view (that's strongly typed to a model) you can do this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BranchNumber, New With { .class = "sr-only" })
```

You also have to annotate your data model with a `Display` attribute like so:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Bank

    Private _branchNumber As String
    <Display(Name:="Branch Number")>
    Public Property BranchNumber() As String
        Get
            Return _branchNumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _branchNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: great response thank you @Html.TextBox("q", Nothing, New With {.class = "form-control", .id = "BranchNumber", .placeholder = "Branch Number", .data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Home")})

Comment: Nice one, I wasn't sure about the dashes in the autocomplete attribute so I just went with the dictionary approach just to be sure =]

Comment: Thanks Sean I am a newbie to mvc 4 coming from a classic asp.net forms. So slowly making the adjustments

Comment: No problem, have fun ^_^

Comment: I am trying to do the same with html helper html.labelfor outputting the following html <label class="sr-only" for="BranchNumber">Branch Number</label> every example points to accessing a model property which I dont want to do

Comment: Stick that in your question and I'll update the answer, it's a little too long to go in a comment =]

Comment: I've put it in the answer anyway, hope that helps =]